# chroot: failed to run command ‘/bin/bash’: No such file or directory (Directory does exist)

Tags: linux, bash, chroot

I am trying to reset my root password for my dedicated CentOS 7 server and keep getting the error below

```
chroot: failed to run command ‘/bin/bash’: No such file or directory
```

I am logged in through "rescue mode" which allows me to reset to password if I forgot it or make any other necessary changes.

I mounted the partition with:

```
# mount /dev/md127 /mnt/
```

But when I try to chroot I get the error that bash does not exist even though it does exist as you can see here:

```
root@rescue:~# chroot /mnt/
chroot: failed to run command ‘/bin/bash’: No such file or directory
root@rescue:~# ls /bin/bash
/bin/bash
root@Rescue:~#
```

Comment: Hi, what Linux distribution are you using, and how are you invoking `chroot`?

Comment: What is your distro?

Comment: I tried ls /mnt/bin/bash but it also says "no such file or directory". I am using CentOS 7

Comment: @user409697 for centos7  just do `mount -o remount,rw /sysroot` and then `chroot /sysroot` it should work.

Comment: @binarysta I tried "mount -o remount,rw /mnt" then "chroot /mnt" and still got the same error

Comment: no please mount `/sysroot` with read/write option. exactly as I have written.

Comment: Tried this at first and got "mount: can't find /sysroot in /etc/fstab"

Comment: The path `/bin/bash` is the path to `bash` _in the chroot_, not outside of the chroot. If the chroot is `/mnt`, then this means `/mnt/bin/bash`.

Comment: Please show us (or check) `ls /mnt`. Since you've said that `/mnt/bin/bash` is missing I'm not at all convinced you've mounted the root filesystem there.

Answer (score 2):

Chroot is complaining because it can't find `/bin/bash` **inside** the chroot environment, so it can't drop you on a shell there. Mount your device, then check inside:

```
# mount /dev/md127 /mnt/
# ls /mnt/bin/bash
```

If I'm guessing right this won't show anything. If there's a valid shell in your chroot you can change your SHELL environment variable. For instance if bash is at (/mnt)/usr/bin/bash:

```
# SHELL=/usr/bin/bash chroot /mnt
```

(Look for sh, csh, dash...)

But you probably don't even need a shell. You can specify the command to run directly when chrooting.

```
# chroot /mnt passwd
```

See `man chroot` for more details.

Also, for changing your password you probably won't need it, but when chrooting for debugging purposes (like if your system doesn't boot) you usually have to bind a few paths like /dev, /dev/tty, /sys and /proc. Eg `mount -o bind /dev /mnt/dev`. So programs can access your devices, process information etc. while in the chrooted environment.

Comment: It fails to bin/bash inside my chroot directory.